# $p$-adic valuation of $x^n+1$[or how many times does a prime number divides $x^n+1$]

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $t \in \mathbb{Q}$ be an arbitrary rational number.
By the term **$p$-adic valuation of $t$**; denoted by $v_p(t)$,
we mean how many times the prime number $p$ divides $t$.

For example:

$v_5(250  )= 3 \ ,  \ \ $
$v_7( 42  )= 1 \ \ \ \ \ , \ \ \ $
$v_3( 81  )= 4 \ \ \ \ \ , \ \ $
$v_2(100^3)= 6 \ , \ \ $
$v_3(108  )= 3 \ , \ \ $

$v_5\left(\dfrac{75}{91}\right)= 2 \ , \ \ $
$v_7\left(\dfrac{11}{98}\right)=-2 \ , \ \ $
$v_3\left(\dfrac{11}{15}\right)=-1 \ , \ \ $
$v_2\left(\dfrac{17}{24}\right)=-3 \ , \ \ $
$v_3\left(\dfrac{18}{41}\right)= 2 \ . \ \ $

---

Let $p$ be a prime, $x$, $y$ are integers. If $v_p(x^n+1)=v_p(y^n+1)$ for every positive integer $n$ and $v_p(x^n+1)$ is not constant for large $n$, can we conclude $x=y$?

Comment: When you say $\Bbb Z_p$, do you mean the $p$-adic integers, or the integers modulo $p$? (Side note: does it matter?)

Comment: p-adic integer, I want to avoid the trivial cases e.g $x=p, y=p^2$

Comment: I assume you want to avoid $x = p+1, y = 2p+1$ as well (which works as long as $p$ is odd)?

Comment: You want $x$ a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$ so that $x^n \equiv - 1 \bmod p$ for some $n$. Otherwise $v_p(x^n+1) = 0$ for every $n$.

Comment: The question reduces to find $y$ with $v_p(y^{b}+1) = v_p(x^b+1)$ where $2b$ is the order of $x \bmod p$

Comment: @reuns, you're right, I will edit this question, in fact I want to know something about the behavior of such p-adic values.

Comment: $v_p(x^{(2k+1)b}+1 ) =v_p(x^b+1)$ and $v_p(x^n+1) = 0$ otherwise

Comment: @Zhiyu Zhang , I think this question maybe, is interesting for you! 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391619/solve-the-following-diophantine-equation-pk-mid-an-1-for-fixed-p-and-k/2391644#2391644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **No**!

---

---

**Lemma(1)**:

- **Part(a)** 
  Let $p$ to be an odd prime number.

$\ \ \ \ \  $ 
Let $a$ and $b$ to be any integers. 
If $ \  \  \nu_p(ab)=0 \ \ $ and $ \  \ 1 \leq \nu_p(a-b) \ , \ $ then for every $n$ we have:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\nu_p\big(a^n-b^n\big)=\nu_p\big(n(a-b)\big)=\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(n)$.

- **Part(b)** 
  Let $p=2$.

$\ \ \ \ \  $ 
Let $a$ and $b$ to be any integers. 
If $ \  \  \nu_2(ab)=0 \ \ $ and  $ \  \ 2 \leq \nu_2(a-b) \ , \ $ then for every $n$ we have:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\nu_2\big(a^n-b^n\big)=\nu_2\big(n(a-b)\big)=\nu_2(a-b)+\nu_2(n)$.

**Lemma(2)**:

- **Part(a)** 
  Let $p$ to be an odd prime number.

$\ \ \ \ \  $ 
Let $a$ and $b$ to be any integers. 
If $ \  \  \nu_p(ab)=0 \ \ $ and  $ \  \ 1 \leq \nu_p(a+b) \ , \ $ then for odd $n$ we have:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\nu_p\big(a^n+b^n\big)=\nu_p\big(n(a+b)\big)=\nu_p(a+b)+\nu_p(n)$.

- **Part(b)** 
  Let $p=2$.

$\ \ \ \ \  $ 
Let $a$ and $b$ to be any integers. 
If $ \  \  \nu_2(ab)=0 \ \ $ and  $ \  \ 2 \leq \nu_2(a+b) \ , \ $ then for odd $n$ we have:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\nu_2\big(a^n+b^n\big)=\nu_2\big(n(a+b)\big)=\nu_2(a+b)+\nu_2(n)$.

---

---

---

---

---

---

**Lemma(3)**: 
Let $p$ to be a prime number. 
Assume that the Lemma holds for $n=r$ and arbitrary $a$ & $b$. 
Also asssume that the Lemma holds for $n=r$ and arbitrary $a$ & $b$. 
then this holds for $n=rs$ and arbitrary $a$ & $b$.

**Proof**: Let $A:=a^r$ & $B:=b^r$.

$ 
\nu_p\big(a^{rs}-b^{rs}\big)= 
\nu_p\Big((a^r)^s-(b^r)^s\Big)= 
\nu_p\big(A^s-B^s\big) 
\overset
{ \tiny {\text {Lemma for $n=s$} } } 
{=} 
\\ 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\nu_p\big(s(A-B)\big)= %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\nu_p(A-B)+\nu_p(s)= 
\nu_p(a^r-b^r)+\nu_p(s) 
\overset
{ \tiny {\text {Lemma for $n=r$} } } 
{=} 
\\ 
\big(\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(r)\big)+\nu_p(s)= 
\nu_p(a-b)+\big(\nu_p(r)+\nu_p(s)\big)= 
\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(rs)$

---

---

**Lemma(4)**:

- **Part(a)** 
  Let $p$ to be an odd prime number.

$\ \ \ \ \  $ 
Let $a$ and $b$ to be any integers. 
If  $ \  \  \nu_p(ab)=0 \ \ $ and $ \  \ 1 \leq \nu_p(a-b) \ , \ $ then we have:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\nu_p\big(a^p-b^p\big)=\nu_p\big(p(a-b)\big)=\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(p)$.

**Proof**: Assume that $a-b=lp^{\nu}$, with $gcd(l,p)=1$ 
and $\nu$ is the abbreviation for $\nu_p(a-b)$. 
Then we have:

$\nu_p \big(a^p-b^p\big)= 
\nu_p \big((lp^{\nu}+b)^p-b^p\big)= 
\nu_p \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{i=p}\Big(C(i,p)(lp^{\nu})^i b^{(p-i)})\Big) \Bigg)= 
\nu_p \Big(C(1,p)(lp^{\nu})^1 b^{(p-1)}\Big)= 
\nu_p \Big(  p   (lp^{\nu})   b^{(p-1)}\Big)= 
\nu_p \Big(  p  .  p^{\nu}             \Big)= 
1+\nu= 
\nu_p(a-b)+1= 
\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(p)
$

So the assertion holds for $n=p$.

---

---

**Lemma(5)**:

- **Part(a)** 
  Let $p$ to be an odd prime number, and let $q \neq p$ to be another distinct prime number.

$\ \ \ \ \  $ 
Let $a$ and $b$ to be any integers. 
If $ \  \  \nu_p(ab)=0 \ \ $ and $ \  \ 1 \leq \nu_p(a-b) \ , \ $ then we have:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\nu_p\big(a^qp-b^q\big)=\nu_p\big(q(a-b)\big)=\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(q)$.

**Proof**: Assume that $a-b=lp^{\nu}$, with $gcd(l,p)=1$ 
and $\nu$ is the abbreviation for $\nu_p(a-b)$ . 
Then we have:

$\nu_p \big(a^q-b^q\big)= 
\nu_p \big((lp^{\nu}+b)^q-b^q\big)= 
\nu_p \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{i=q}\Big(C(i,q)(lp^{\nu})^i b^{(q-i)})\Big) \Bigg)= 
\nu_p \Big(C(1,q)(lp^{\nu})^1 b^{(q-1)}\Big)= 
\nu_p \Big(  q   (lp^{\nu})   b^{(q-1)}\Big)= 
\nu_p \Big(  q     p^{\nu}             \Big)= 
\nu= 
\nu_p(a-b)+0= 
\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(q)
$

So the assertion holds for $n=q$.

---

---

**Proof of the lemma(1), Part(a)**. We will prove the Lemma(1) by induction on $n$.
By considering the Lemma(3) it only suffices to prove the lemma for prime exponents, which already we have done in lemma(4) and lemma(5).

---

---

**Proof of the lemma(2)**: Let $a^{\prime}=a$, $b^{\prime}=-b$. 
It only suffices to notice that for odd $n$ we have:

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
a^n+b^n=a^{\prime ^ n}-b^{\prime ^ n}$.

Now it can easily derived from lemma(1).

---

---

The answer is **No**!

At first suppose that $p$ is odd, and let $x=p-1$ and $y=2p-1$.

- If $n$ is odd; then we have: 
  $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
  \nu_p(x^n+1)=\nu_p(x+1)+\nu_p(n)=
  \nu_p(y+1)+\nu_p(n)=\nu_p(y^n+1)$.
- If $n$ is even; then we have: 
  $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
  \nu_p(x^n+1)=0=\nu_p(y^n+1)$.

Comment: Where can I find proofs of these two useful lemmas？

Comment: And how to handle the case p=2？

Comment: At first forgive me for the mistake in the lemma. Notice  that we must have: $p \nmid ab$. But in fact this condition does not restrict us, because we can factor the $p$ part. For example 

$ \nu_5(300^{375}-50^{375})= \nu_5\big( 25^{375} ( 12^{375}-2^{375} )\big) = 
\\ 
2*375+ \nu_5(12^{375}-2^{375})= 2*375+ \nu_5(12-2)+ \nu_5(375)$

Comment: $Zhiyu Zhang , Does this answer satisfies you?