# Prove that $5^{3^n} + 1$ is divisible by $3^{n + 1}$ for all nonnegative integers $n.$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction, divisibility

Prove that $5^{3^n} + 1$ is divisible by $3^{n + 1}$ for all nonnegative integers $n.$

I tried to use Proof by Induction, but I'm stuck on the case for when $n=k+1.$

Comment: This should not be tagged [tag:linear-algebra]

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411847/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591176/42969.

Comment: Sorry guys. Didn't know that this question was already answered...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$5^{3^{k+1}}+1=(5^{3^k})^3+1=(5^{3^k}+1)(5^{2\cdot3^k}-5^{3^k}+1)$

Comment: Thank you for the hint!